# When my iPhone is hooked up to iTunes, I can't sort music by Album

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

iPhone 5s
iTunes 11.2.2.3
Windows 7 OS

I synch on my Mac Pro at home...

When I get to work I have to use a Windows machine.

I authorized my iTunes app on my work machine.

When I view my iPhone music in iTunes, I can only sort by name and not by any other column.

How can I sort by Album when looking at music on my iPhone in iTunes?

EDIT

Picture added
See good column in green and nasty stupid head columns in red.

No comments about my music choices allowed...lol
[image: View of my iPhone songs in iTunes]

Comment: Do you mean that when you click on the "Album" header, nothing happens?

Comment: Yes; at home, the column headers do their thing and I can sort on any column. At work, clicking the other columns do nothing. I updated my question with a pic

Comment: Did my answer below solve your problem? If so, please mark it as the solution so the question can be closed. Thanks

Comment: If I turn that on, and click apply, then iTunes says - Hey! I'll wipe your whole iPhone library just for fun! Is that OK? NO... So how do I get my iPhone music on my work PC so I can synch without erasing everything?!? I realize that's a different question, but I don't know if you're solution works because I don't want to wipe my phone...

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. In your question you stated that you sync your iPhone with the library on your Mac Pro at home. Do you also want to sync with the library on your work PC?

Comment: No - I just want to play it at work. I can't sort anything when at work from the issue described above. It's seems ridiculous that you must synch the iPhone JUST to sort music by album, artist, or some other attribute.

Comment: Click `Manually manage music and videos`. It may wipe your iPhone library the first time (don't know why it feels the need to do this, but oh well). Then just re-sync at home, and the next time you use your iPhone at work everything will be working like you want

Comment: Really? Ok - I'll try that. It's still silly of Apple to do it this way.

Comment: Now I get to drive home with no music. lol If this works tomorrow, I'll mark yours as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your iPhone connected, go to the `Summary` page and check `Manually manage music and videos`.

Comment: Good to hear! The option should stay set until you manually uncheck it.

Comment: still works in iOS8/iTunes 12

Comment: Annoying that it wants to wipe your phone just to enable "manage manually" so I can get some freaking sort columns!

Comment: @craig itunes fυcking sucks for exactly this reason